# How can I fill green the chapter in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, colorbox

How can I fill green the chapter in table of contents like this:
[image]

I have read many place (for example [Using colors in LaTeX document](https://texblog.org/2015/05/20/using-colors-in-a-latex-document/), [Generate a table of contents](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/table-of-contents/),...) but I could not found any ideas for it.

Help me! Thanks a lot!

P/s: The full file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bo2qXq1-M31EMm_fvBB40hS7ONs7QCte/view?fbclid=IwAR2RQM6wy-U7wRNfdhn1GTz1tSjVBglVpUHpmWrJ5Nt7jzmPdw2Uvk6pEQk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a starting point:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
 {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[fill=teal,draw=none] (-.3,-0.2) rectangle (\textwidth,0.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \color{white}\large\bfseries}
 {\thecontentslabel\quad}
 {}
 {\normalsize\hfill\thecontentspage}
 [\addvspace{1.5ex}]
\titlecontents{section}[0cm]
  {\bfseries}
  {\thecontentslabel\quad}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
 \chapter{Chapter title}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, but every times when I type it in Texstudio and update the tables of contents, I found with this I have to click "Build and View" twice . Right?

Comment: Yes, in order to get the table of contents correctly, you have to compile twice every time you add or update a sectioning command. You can press  F6. Then you can view the pdf with F7